# MVC4 validation not working after IIS deployment, but in Visual studio server its working fine

Tags: java, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis-7

I am working  on a MVC4 application, here everything is working fine on Visual studio server like "client side" validation messages.

[image: Client side validation in visual studio server]

But when I publish this project and deploy in IIS its not working at all, confused with solution. Is there any code needed to add or IIS configuration issue? ere is UI block code, I am using Jquery-1.9.1, please help me out. Might I be missing IIS configurations, if any?

```
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip)
         <span style="float:right;">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zip)</span><br>
         <span style="float:right;">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip)</span><br>
```

in Model :

```
[DisplayName("Zip")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Length can't be more than 5.")]
        [RegularExpression("([0-9]{5})", ErrorMessage = "Enter valid 5 digit numeric values")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's probably due to a JS library file not loading correctly. Have you checked the paths are correct, and that there are no errors in the console?

Comment: @Rory  i m getting this in browser console..
 TypeError: n(...).live is not a function
...iveAjaxClick",f="unobtrusiveValidation";n("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click",func...  For this i did changes in unobstructive.ajax.js file by removing deprecated .live() code..but still no luck

Comment: `live()` was removed from the jQuery source a *long* time ago. It sounds like you need to both update the version of jQuery you use in your local copy and use the delegated version of `on()` instead.

Comment: `by removing deprecated .live() code` did you removed that code or replaced it with `on`? also try by replacing all occurrences of `live` with `on`. And then try by clearing browser cache.

Comment: yes exactly, as i googled. i removed those deprecated functions from jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js as required, and same copy from my local i m publishing to IIS.

Comment: wooowww...finally, i just tried some trial and error, and published that project in VS2010 no wits working fine in IIS too. Previously i was working in VS13 ..might some .js files version issue. Thanks to @Rory McCrossan and @ ramiramilu

Answer (score 0):

This will occur when you use the buggy `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js` library that is referenced by default on MVC5 projects and deployed it before updating your development code with the correct `jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.js` library.

Just remove the `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js` and `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.min.js` on your Scripts folder on your IIS to resolve this.